# Load inline JS after page load

Tags: javascript, html

I want to load an inline JavaScript after the page has fully loaded.
The reason is, that the scripts loads an external JS file which I don't want to block the rendering of the page.

This is the whole code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
var _tsid = 'XXXX';
_tsConfig = {
  'yOffset': '0', // offset from page bottom
  'variant': 'custom_reviews', // default, reviews, custom, custom_reviews
  'customElementId': 'MyCustomTrustbadge', // required for variants custom and custom_reviews
  'trustcardDirection': 'bottomLeft', // for custom variants: topRight, topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft
  'customBadgeWidth': '', // for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels)
  'customBadgeHeight': '', // for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels)
  'disableResponsive': 'false', // deactivate responsive behaviour
  'disableTrustbadge': 'false' // deactivate trustbadge
};
var _ts = document.createElement('script');
_ts.type = 'text/javascript';
_ts.charset = 'utf-8';
_ts.async = true;
_ts.src = '//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/' + _tsid + '.js';
var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
__ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);
})();
</script>
```

I know that I could maybe use `$(document).ready`. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason is, that the scripts loads an external JS file which I don't want to block the rendering of the page.

Adding [the `defer` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) to the script element will defer execution until the DOM is ready while allowing the script to be downloaded in parallel.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how to do that in the code above :-(

Comment: `_ts.defer = true` instead of `async`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to enclose the execution of your code in an EventListener wich executes if the DOMContent is fully loaded.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var _tsid = 'XXXX';
  _tsConfig = {
    'yOffset': '0', // offset from page bottom
     // default, reviews, custom, custom_reviews
    'variant': 'custom_reviews',
    // required for variants custom and custom_reviews
    'customElementId': 'MyCustomTrustbadge',
    // for custom variants: topRight, 
    // topLeft, bottomRight, bottomLeft
    'trustcardDirection': 'bottomLeft', 
    'customBadgeWidth': '', // for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels)
    'customBadgeHeight': '', // for custom variants: 40 - 90 (in pixels)
    'disableResponsive': 'false', // deactivate responsive behaviour
    'disableTrustbadge': 'false' // deactivate trustbadge
  };
  var _ts = document.createElement('script');
  _ts.type = 'text/javascript';
  _ts.charset = 'utf-8';
  _ts.async = true;
  _ts.src = '//widgets.trustedshops.com/js/' + _tsid + '.js';
  var __ts = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  __ts.parentNode.insertBefore(_ts, __ts);
});
</script>
```

Comment: This loses the benefits of being able to download the JS in parallel.